# SEO Optimization- PHP project for Dynamic files

Tags: php, optimization, seo

I am creating a site/new to php.

I know that web crawlers look at URLs to help them sift through content, but if all the content is on dynamic pages? For instance, say I have a site for bloggers- and blogger A creates a blog called "cooking with the oldies" . **blog.php?id=7**

and

blogger B creates a blog called "my life in finland". **blog.php?id=10**

both point to **blog.php** - but the content changes based on id passed.
is it possible to create fake folder structures like:

blog/blogger a/cooking with the oldies/

blog/blogger b/my life in finland/

I am under the assumption this will make the site more SEO friendly.

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction of what to look at as far as tutorials,etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. If using Apache, take a look at the .htaccess configuration using mod_rewrite. If you're using Windows/IIS then you'll want to try using the web.server/Rewrite section of the web.config.

Something like this for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view_pic/(.*)/(.*)?/?$ /veiw_pic.php?what=$1&pic=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^coverart?/?$ /coverart.php [QSA]
```

Or something like this for IIS:

```
<system.webServer> 
<defaultDocument> 
  <files> 
    <clear /> 
    <add value="index.php" /> 
  </files> 
</defaultDocument> 
<rewrite> 
  <rules> 
    <rule name="viewpic" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url="^view_pic/(.*)/(.*)?/?$" /> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/view_pic.php?what={R:1}&amp;pic={R:2}" /> 
    </rule> 
    <rule name="coverart" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url="^coverart?/?$" /> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/coverart.php" /> 
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```